# rem not outputing value relative to body font , em works fine

Tags: css, font-size

I have the following section on which i need a padding top and padding bottom of approximately `85px`.

So my section looks like the following:

[image]

My body element has a `font-size` of `16px` and so i apply the following styles to the section for padding:

```
.careers-highlight-contact-section {
    padding-top: 5.31rem;
    padding-bottom: 5.31rem;
}
```

The way i get 5.31 is 85/16, but now when i check the computed values , i see that the padding top and padding bottom is actually `53px`. How does it come to this value ?

You can see this error on this link [here](http://codeandcode.co/demo/space-edge/html/V10/careers.php).

If you change the padding values from rem to em then you get the correct height. Why is this happening ?

[image]

Comment: That is because `rem` is relative to the root font size, i.e. font-size declared on the `<html>` element, not `<body>`. If you change the font-size on that element to 16px, you will see the correct padding being calculated (but that also messes up other font sizes, so it's good to go through all your font size declarations again).

Comment: @Terry ! facepalm , `html { font-size:16px  }` , is what i need :) TY for pointing out my silly mistake ! :)

Comment: No worries, I have been there before, too ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you refer to the W3C spec, the `rem` unit is defined as:

> Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element.
>
> When specified on the ‘font-size’ property of the root element, the ‘rem’ units refer to the property's initial value.

Therefore, as per my comment, the `rem` bases its calculations off the font-size declared on the root element, i.e. the `<html>` element instead of the `<body>` element. As long as you declare `font-size: 16px` on the former, you will see that a correct padding will be calculated.

Answer (score 4):

`rem` is relative to the default size, which is either defined by the browser OR by you, however not in the CSS rule for `body`, but in the rule for `html`.

Your calculation and result fits a default size of 16px, which is the default font-size in most browsers. If you define a different font-size for `html`, the padding should change.